# Azure pipeline, npmAuthenticate task in custom docker container

Tags: docker, npm, azure-pipelines

I am trying to use npmAuthenticate task in azure pipeline which is running script in custom docker container

```
container:
  image: android_builder:37878
  endpoint: sc-acr

steps:
- task: npmAuthenticate@0
  inputs:
    workingFile: '.npmrc'
- script: |
    npm i
```

The azure private registry is in my organisation, but `npm install` is failing because of auth
I haven't found a example of using this task in docker container in documentation, so not sure if this works in this way

Answer (score 1):

the npm authenticate task is just for task runners. You can use the npm task itself, with your private registry as a custom feed

```yaml
- task: Npm@1
  inputs:
    command: 'install'
    customRegistry: 'useFeed'
    customFeed: '<YOUR FEED ID>'
```

Comment: According to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/npm?view=azure-devops)
npm authenticate is the recommended way.
I tried the above, npm task failed with the error `npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded`
npm install works if I copy-paste token in my .npmrc file, but its not ideal way as that token should not be committed with repo

Comment: are you trying to build in a `Dockerfile`? If so, you can have a multi-stage build